# Why is pointer src (and c) being modified?

Tags: c, pointers

For some reason the pointer src (and the array it points, c) gets modified when executing `dest = ft_strcpy(dest, src)` and printing it, giving some trash value at the beggining. However, if I just print the result of the function without doing the previous equalization, i.e, `write(1, ft_strcpy(dest, src), 10)`, everything goes well. I know I can put directly c and c2, the error stays the same.

In short, doing `dest = ft_strcpy(dest, src)` if with the array pointed by dest (c2) is shorter than c + 1, results in c getting modified.

```
char    *ft_strcpy(char *dest, char *src)
{
    char    *ptr1;
    char    *ptr2;

    ptr1 = src;
    ptr2 = dest;
    while (*src != '\0')
    {
        *dest = *src;
        src++;
        dest++;
    }
    *dest = '\0';
    src = ptr1;
    dest = ptr2;
    return (dest);
}


int main (void)
{
    char c[10] = "Hola Pepe ";
    char c2[10];
    char *src, *dest;
    src = c;
    dest = c2;

    write(1, src, 10);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    write(1, dest, 10);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    dest = ft_strcpy(dest, src);
    write(1, "----------\n", 11);
    write(1, src, 10);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    write(1, dest, 10);
    //write(1, ft_strcpy(dest, src), 10);
}
```

Comment: `char c[10]` is not big enough to store your null terminator.  You're overrunning your buffer.

Comment: `*(dest + 1) = '\0';` You probably don't want the `+1` here, `dest` has already been incremented in the loop.

Comment: You can avoid this issue by letting the compiler count for you: `char c[] = "Hola Pepe ";`

Comment: How do you know the pointer src is modified - not the thing it points to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `main()` your buffer `c` can hold up to 10 `char`s. But the string you assign to it is made up of 11 `char`s (including the NUL terminator `\0`).

So it should be declared as:

`char c[11] = "Hola Pepe ";`

Or if you want to leave the counting to the compiler:

`char c[] = "Hola Pepe ";`

You should also make sure your `c2` buffer is big enough to hold whatever you want to copy into it:

```
char c2[11];
```

In the following code:

```
while (*src != '\0') {

       *dest = *src;
       src++; 
       dest++;
} 

*(dest + 1)= '\0';
```

In the final iteration, the `dest++` statement is executed which increments `dest` to where the `\0` should be placed (at the end of the string).

In the line:

```
*(dest + 1) = '\0';
```

You increment `dest` once more and then store `\0` inside it. This is not what you want.

Instead you can just do the following and it will correctly terminate the string:

`*dest = '\0';`